# Recode column values based on previous values

Tags: text-processing

```
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 1 1 2
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 1 1 2
1859116 2255037 21608 Yes 06S14028969 11 0 2 3
1859117 2268746 34027 Yes 06S14028970 10 0 2 1
```

Above is the example of my data set. I want to replace the values of 7th column in a way that 1 should be replaced to 2 and 0 should be replaced by 1. So the outcome I am expecting should be like following.

```
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 2 1 2
1859115 2258379 24636 Yes 06S14028968 13 2 1 2
1859116 2255037 21608 Yes 06S14028969 11 1 2 3
1859117 2268746 34027 Yes 06S14028970 10 1 2 1
```

I have tried using this approach

```
awk 'NR==1{$10="Pheno";print;next}\
 $7 == "1" {$10="2"};\
 $7 == "0" {$10="1"}1'  old.txt |column -t > new.txt
```

and then removing the first row. But I need straight forward way.

Comment: You say you want to replace the value in the 7th column, but your awk code is changing the value in the 10th column. Which one is actually correct?

Comment: Am I right in guessing that the code in your question adding a new line containing `Pheno` is undesirable and your solution is `and then removing the first row` as you can't figure out how to change the awk code to not produce that line in the first place and that you copy/pasted the code in your question from elsewhere and have no idea how it works or what it's doing?

Answer (score 3):

if column 7<sup>th</sup>'s value is always 0 or 1, you could use:

```
awk 'NR>1{ $7+=1 }1' infile
```

if not, then check its value if it's either 0 or 1:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $7 ~/^[01]$/ { $7+=1 }1' infile
```

---

it's looks like that you adds the modified value as a new column in your code, if you need print it in a new column, do as following with the same assumption that column 7<sup>th</sup>'s value is always 0 or 1:

```
awk '{ print $0, (NR==1?"Pheno":++$7) }' infile
```

otherwise:

```
awk '{ print $0, (NR==1?"Pheno":($7 ~/^[01]$/?++$7:"NA") ) }' infile
```

---

Note: change `$7 ~/^[01]$/` to `($7==1 || $7==0)` to strictly checks that their value is really a number rather than using previous one (`$7 ~/^[01]$/`) that checks for a single integer digit 0 or 1 only which as a result that won't work for floating points number such as `1.0` or `0.0` or number with leading zeros like `000` or `001`, etc.